# How to pass user input from one activity to another in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm creating a basic conversion app which converts the users input from km-knots or vice versa. At present it displays the result in the same place as where the user initially type in their figure. I'm wondering how is it possible to display the result in a new activity? Currently I've only managed to make it appear, as I said, in the same place as where the user initially type in their figure and a second afterwards the second activity pops up. What am I missing here? Please look at my code, thanks:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package winfield.joe.wind.v1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // public var
    private EditText text;

    // default func
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // findViewById = Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute
        // from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
        // (EditText) = typecast
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    }

    //Will be executed by clicking on the calculate button because we assigned "calc" to the "onClick" Property

    public void calc(View view) {

        RadioButton toKilometers = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.toKilometers);
        RadioButton toKnots = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.toKnots);

        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            // if the text field is empty show the message "enter a valid number" via toast message
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            int result = R.string.userInput;
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            putExtra("userInput", result); 
            startActivity(i);

            // parse input Value from Text Field
            double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
            // convert to...
            if (toKilometers.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKM(inputValue)));
                // uncheck "to km" Button
                toKilometers.setChecked(false);
                // check "to knots" Button
                toKnots.setChecked(true);
            } else { /* if toKnots button isChecked() */
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKnots(inputValue)));
                // uncheck "to knots" Button
                toKnots.setChecked(false);
                // check "to km" Button
                toKilometers.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

    }


    private void putExtra(String string, int result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private double convertToKM(double inputValue) {
        // convert knots to km
        return (inputValue * 1.8);
    }

    private double convertToKnots(double inputValue) {
        // convert km to knots
        return (inputValue * 0.539956803);
    }

}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package winfield.joe.wind.v1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int result = extras.getInt("results"); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

    //onClick GoBack method assigned to the Go Back? button which returns the user to main activity from the second activity
    public void GoBack(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure?");

            // set dialog message
            builder .setCancelable(false)

                    .setPositiveButton("Convert Again",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            //You return to Main Activity  
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })

                    .setNeutralButton("Back to Home",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            //You return to the home page
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("View Results",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--TITLE-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/titleMain"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorLink="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <!--USER-INPUT-->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@+string/userInput"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

      <!--TWO RADIO BUTTONS-->
      <LinearLayout

          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingRight="10dp">

          <!--toKNOTS-->

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/toKnots"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.04"
              android:checked="true"
              android:text="@string/toKnots" />

          <!--toKM-->

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/toKilometers"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:text="@string/toKilometers" />

      </LinearLayout>

      <!--CALCULATE-->

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/valueCalc"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
          android:onClick="calc"
          android:text="@string/valueCalc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <!-- TITLE -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/titleResults"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorLink="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/results"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/GoBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/GoBack"
        android:onClick="GoBack" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
03-09 12:27:35.692: E/AndroidRuntime(2911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:27:35.692: E/AndroidRuntime(2911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:27:45.262: E/AndroidRuntime(2934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:27:45.262: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:29:52.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:29:52.172: E/AndroidRuntime(2989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:32:29.322: E/AndroidRuntime(3056): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:32:29.322: E/AndroidRuntime(3056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:36:29.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:36:29.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:44:25.022: E/AndroidRuntime(3172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:44:25.022: E/AndroidRuntime(3172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 12:53:38.802: E/AndroidRuntime(3242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 12:53:38.802: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-09 13:19:58.122: E/AndroidRuntime(3299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{winfield.joe.wind.v1/winfield.joe.wind.v1.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 13:19:58.122: E/AndroidRuntime(3299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: You cannot edit my answer to explain the error you are getting, please write comments on my answer so I can understand what the problem you are still having.

Comment: Sorry about that, clicked the wrong button.. i submitted more progress under your answer. Thanks, J.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass any content from one activity to another, you can do it by using `putExtra` with intent, it will send data from one activity to another, and in another activity get that data by using `getExtras`.

To send data,

```
String str = "value";
Intent launchResult = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
putExtra("key", str);
startActivity(launchResult);
```

To receive data in another activity,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String str = extras.getStr("key");
```

**Edit:**

In my answer `key` is any **unique value** that must remain same in both `Sender Activity` and `Receiver Activity`.

You are getting the error because you have passed a **string value** where you had to pass **key**, and the key in receiver activity in not matching either.

See the change below, it should work

`MainActivity.class`

```
int result = R.string.userInput;
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
putExtra("userInput", result); 
startActivity(i);
```

`SecondActivity.class`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int result = extras.getInt("userInput");
```

Comment: Sorry about that Apurva, clicked edit instead of reply.

In my main activity i entered:

 `code`
int result = R.string.userInput;
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        putExtra(getString(R.string.userInput), result);
        startActivity(i);
`code`


and in my second activity i entered:


`code`
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtra();
int result = extras.getInt("userInput");
`code`

To suit my data types and id's but i'm still getting errors.. any ideas?

Comment: Oh ok, i see why. There's only one error now which is on the 

`code`
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtra();
`code`

Which reads: "The method getExtra() is undefined for the type Intent". There's about 20-30 suggested fixes though.

Comment: That fixes the error in Eclipse but now when i click my button to change activities, it crashes. I'm not too sure why, there aren't any errors. I'm not too sure what else I can show you..?

Comment: @joewinfield91 edit your question and add your `logcat` errors, so I can understand why your app crashes.

Comment: I can edit my question yes, but i've about 100+ logcat errors so it might be hard to read all of them in this comment section, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe i could sent you my app folder?

Comment: @joewinfield91 you can still post, do you see red lines in logcat? All those are errors. Post in your question.

Comment: I reuploaded my .java and .xml files but when i added the logcat errors I went over the character count limit in stackoverflow questions so i couldn't include them. Maybe if I added the AndroidRunTime filter?

Comment: I added the logcat messages now, there seems to be alot less this time.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to pass values from one Activity to Another

```
Intent launchResult = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
launchResult.putExtra("output",result);
```